# Incorrect integer value: '' for column error

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting 'Incorrect integer value: '' for column country_id'. Sometimes my dropdown is hidden in the form. So I am not sure how to handle this situtation. Here is my code. Thanks for any help.

```
$countryId = isset($_POST['country']) ? $_POST['country'] : 0;

$inserSQL = "INSERT INTO Table1(country_id) VALUES('" .$countryId. "')";

$Result1 = mysql_query($inserSQL ) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: A little bit obvious but...where's the double or single quotes around the Sql statement?

Comment: Look ant the EmCo answer. it has everything you need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are adding `'` to the `$countryId` value. Since an integer is expected, you don't have to use them. Try this:

```
$countryId = isset($_POST['country']) ? (int)$_POST['country'] : 0;

$inserSQL = "INSERT INTO Table1(country_id) VALUES($countryId)";

$Result1 = mysql_query($inserSQL ) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: The real issue is not the quotes around the data but the fact that $_POST['country'] may come back blank or empty.    MySQL will interpret '' as an empty STRING not an int whereas '0' it will recognize and auto-convert to an int.      This code works because of the (int) typecast on $_POST['country'] which turns (int)'' into 0.

Answer (score 0):

I once experienced this problem and apparently i had a typo instead of putting a `0` i typed an `O` "Letter O" and that value was not expected in the database because the database field only accepted integers.

Make sure in your the value being passed from your code is integer type.